# How to add a marker while exporting a maplibre map while exporting to pdf

Tags: maplibre-gl

The marker is visible on the map but while exporting to pdf the marker is not getting exported.

My code looks like:

```
map.addLayer({
            id: 'mapLine',
            type: 'circle',
            source: {
                type: 'geojson',
                data: {
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: [
                        {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Point',
                                coordinates: [-77.03238901390978, 38.913188059745586],
                            },
                            properties: {},
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
            paint: {
                'circle-radius': 8,
                'circle-color': 'red',
                'circle-stroke-width': 1,
                'circle-blur': 0.5,
            },
        });
```

But while exporting to pdf the marker is not showing up.